# How to remove all character,number and word after id at link from wp-posts description?

Tags: wordpress

I have several links across many WordPress posts which look something like this:

```
domain.com/12345/-bla-bla-1-bla
domain.com/123456/-bla-bla-2-bla
domain.com/124589/-bla-bla-0-bla
```

How can I trim off all the characters after the number to produce urls like this?

```
domain.com/12345
domain.com/123456
domain.com/124589
```

Comment: i am newbie.. i have 1 link at every post description.. any suggestion? to remove it using php or manualy remove all by use command direct from phpmyadmin? I want to remove all the character after domain.com/12345

Comment: i mean not remove one by one manualy cause i have 1000+ post.